# How to include a dash(-) character in the Natural key

Tags: acumatica

A custom DAC has a PK that is 10 characters length.  The characters include a dash.  Example:  10-117ASKP.  I notice that it's not possible to type the dash character, in the UI.  So I'm unable to assign the value.  I added the correct value directly in the database table.  The record is saved, but the UI shows the value without the dash.  How to accomplish the goal?

Comment: You need to define a Segmented Key with 2 segments(2 character and 7 character)

Comment: Could be a mask on the field in the DAC? Also try a maskedit field vs textedit to see if that makes a difference in the page. Is the string set as unicode string field in PXDBString?